# Latex in Ubuntu

Tags: latex

There is no internet connection in my laptop. However net is in my office desktop & I have USB. I want to install latex in my laptop. Is it possible? My version is Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a handful of methods for [loading of TexLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html) onto a non-networked machine.

Depending on your requirements, this is often better than loading from the Ubuntu repositories as they lag behind the latest and greatest from tug.org. TeX/LaTeX is relatively free of system dependencies, so you are unlikely to have issues installing as you might with more tightly coupled packages.